# How to check if a selected item from an editable Combobox is empty

Tags: java, string, swing, combobox, null

I have an editable `ComboBox` where the user can select a database or type the name of a new one and press `Enter` or the button `Create` to create it.

What I have found is a strange behavior of the `Editable ComboBox`, if say there was something selected in the combobox like this:

[image: 1]

and then the user deletes it like this:

[image: 2]

and presses the `Enter key` or the `Create` button, then this code is not enough to check if there is no selected item in the `ComboBox`:

```
if (jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem() == null) {
    return;
}
```

So I opted to check it like this:

```
if (jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem() == null
       || jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
```

My question is: is my way of checking the selected item cheap and is there a more elegant way?

---

Here is how I did it in the end:

**ComboBox and Create button**

```
private void jDatabaseComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                  
    {                                                      
        final String selectedDatabaseName = jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem().
                toString().trim();
        if (selectedDatabaseName.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        if (databaseAlreadyExistsInServer(selectedDatabaseName)) {
            _currentDatabase = new SQLDatabase(selectedDatabaseName);
            updateTableComboBoxes();
        } else {
            createANewDatabase(selectedDatabaseName);
            updateDatabaseComboBoxes();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Delete Button**

```
private void jDeleteDatabaseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
        final String selectedDatabaseName = jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem().
                toString().trim();

        if (selectedDatabaseName.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!databaseAlreadyExistsInServer(selectedDatabaseName)) {
            return;
        }

        deleteDatabase(selectedDatabaseName);
        updateDatabaseComboBoxes();
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I don't check for `null` anymore because I have it so that if the `comboBoxes` are empty then they will be grayed out.

Comment: What's the problem in your last option? What are you thinking? Why you say it cheap?

Comment: @Braj it seems to me like my last option is cheap and may cause unexpected bugs. More like I'm asking if it can cause unexpected bugs that I haven't accounted for and if there is a better way.

Comment: One mistake - you have called `jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()` before checking null.

Comment: @Braj Would that throw an exception if I try to convert a null value into string?

Comment: if selected item is null then calling `null.toString()` will result in null pointer exception.

Comment: Should I edit it for you in your question itself?

Comment: Now that I think about it the comboBox will never return a null value. I have made it so if there are no databases then the comboBox and the buttons will be grayed out but I guess it would be bad programming practice to leave it alone. Sure edit it.

Comment: Alright I'll leave it be then and just edit the code now and say why I don't check for `null` anymore.

Comment: Read [ComboBoxModel#getSelectedItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) that says : Returns : `The selected item or null if there is no selection`. You have to put a `null` check because it can return a null value as per JavaDoc. Sorry You and me both are wrong on it. :)

Comment: @Braj True. What I didn't know and confused me is that if it as editable one then it pretty much never returns `null`. It will actually return an empty String.

Comment: Sorry I can't say but if you have tested all the test cases then go ahead with this.

Comment: Yes it won't throw a null exception no matter what I do at it show I'll keep it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way:

```
comboBox.getSelectedIndex()
```

**it will return -1 if the value is empty or null or not valid(matched) value.**

Find the sample code here [Editable ComboBox](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/EditableComboBox.htm)

---

--EDIT--

Delete button is clicked

```
if (jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
    System.out.println("Please select a database name.");
} else {
    System.out.println("database name is deleted successfully.");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if someone types a new database name and presses the `Enter` key or the `Create` button because the new name is not an item of the comboBox so it returns -1.

Comment: This sample checks whether a valid value is selected or not. Its not for accepting new values as you want to create a new database name. Your requirement is some what different from this but still you can use this approach if in future you want to validate the value from a static Editable combo box.

Comment: At least You can use this condition in case of delete option.

Comment: What about the situation? If a existing database name is selected and click on create button. In that case also you can use this condition.

Comment: I will use it for the delete button thank you. About the `Create` button if I have a database say "apples" already and the user types "apples" and presses `Enter` or `Create` I can't have it to check against the values of the ComboBox because there is a chance that the database might have disconnected. In that case I have it to check directly with the server to see if the database exists or not.

Comment: I am updating my post. Please wait for a minute.

Comment: OK I have done. Please have a look. It might help your.

Comment: Its fine with create button as per your application design. I will update my post just for delete button.

Comment: I think in the end I will use the same method for code consistency but thanks for your help. I updated how I did it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

add trim to your check

```
 jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().isEmpty()
```

to check for only spaces as input. Also try using StringUtils of lang of apache. You can replace the whole line with just one line

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(jDatabaseComboBox.getSelectedItem()))
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html